# Google Contacts API returning 401 even though the App is authenticated

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, google-signin

So, I am working on the Android side of an App where I am required to let a user share an image to his or her Google contacts. For this, I obviously require the authorization of the user to access his or her Google contacts. The way, we have achieved this is as follows:

- On Android, I am using Google's standard Auth Sign in API(with OAuth 2.0)
- On Backend, I am using the Contacts API to retrieve the contacts to send the contacts to the device(*I know you might be wondering why am I not using the contacts API on mobile directly but the original API arrangement has been written by someone else*)

So, I simply follow the process Google's OAuth arrangement dictates. First I request for an API authorization grant code. Next, I send this code to get an access token and then finally send this access token to my server to make a call through Contacts API.

The request access screen I get when asking for authorization from a user is:

[image]

So finally the Contacts API sends the following request(*sample request out of many*):

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full?alt=json&access_token=ya29.GluXBJvdEgHD4XrieSgukvfvE0-XlNSwxDF8aaLMLHaXxE3Qd6G2Gy2h18WUOvOg--U0ffobyEzJiXIWtW2sRtdND8B6zcCVrvQm0kfOSBAJcdA4-9i6JZ7CH8y1&v=3.0

But the response returned is 401. Why would it be unauthenticated, I don't understand. I have debugged for several hours and checked that the OAuth process is working completely fine.

One more thing, I am using the the following scopes to sign in to Google:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(CLIENT_ID, true)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
                .build();
```

Does anyone what might be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I am providing a few more details demonstrating that the setup of API keys, OAuth IDs, etc. have been done right.

- First, I am using a Web Application OAuth client ID to request for a Authorization code from Google as dictated in the official guide [**here**](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id).
- The SHA-1 debug fingerprint of my App has been added to my project so Google is not complaining about that.
- The redirect URL that I am using after receiving access token has also been added to my Web OAuth client.
- The Contacts API that I am using server side is enabled for my project.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, it turned out to be an issue with `Scope`.

First, let me tell you that I generally love Google's awesome documentation and APIs but there are cases where the *seemingly trivial* details are taken for granted and developers feel like shooting themselves debugging them. I felt, this was one of those issues.

So, anyone starting the Google Sign-in integration would go through the official docs and guides and there **is** mention and usage of scopes in the docs but something like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(CLIENT_ID, true)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE), new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
                .build();
```

This is from a sample snippet. Of course, the developers copy from sample snippet and further extend it. So, as a developer, how would I extend on this?

Well, for starters, I can clearly pass more scopes right?

That's right, I did that BUT still got struck in this problem. After all, all I had to do was add the appropriate scope right. How could anyone get struck like that? Let me show you what the `Scopes` class looks like:

```
public final class Scopes {
    public static final java.lang.String PROFILE = "profile";
    public static final java.lang.String EMAIL = "email";
    public static final java.lang.String PLUS_LOGIN = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
    public static final java.lang.String PLUS_ME = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
    public static final java.lang.String GAMES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games";
    public static final java.lang.String CLOUD_SAVE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastoremobile";
    public static final java.lang.String APP_STATE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appstate";
    public static final java.lang.String DRIVE_FILE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
    public static final java.lang.String DRIVE_APPFOLDER = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_LOCATION_READ = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.write";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_BODY_READ = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read";
    public static final java.lang.String FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.write";

    private Scopes() { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

So, a developer thinks,

> "these are all the scopes supported and all I have to do is refer to a
>   *valid* scope with `Scopes.SCOPE_NAME`"

**But guess what? There is more to the Scopes story!**

Turns out you can create your own scope with an endpoint of Google's API you are targeting. In my case, it was the Contacts API I was using so the new code looked like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(CLIENT_ID, true)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE), new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL), new Scope("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
                .build();
```

Did you notice the additional Scope:

```
new Scope("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/")
```

Yep, that's it. That's the answer.

**So, what tingled my Spidey sense after all?**

You see that in the above permission page that Google presented, it didn't mention anything about Contacts. But, I want access to Contacts. That's an obvious red flag right there!

After you add the additional scope, it showed, "*wants to manage your contacts*".(your aha! moment)

One last thing -

**How did I know about the URI for the Scope?**

Well, that's an easy one. You are most likely to find it in the doc/guide of the respective API you are targeting. Also, look out for it in the provided samples. So, next time you get struck with authentication, look for correct scope as the first probability.